# Data augmentation workflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, dataset

What is the more common approach to augmenting data (in the case of an image dataset, creating random crops, etc.), doing it on the fly during training or creating a standalone dataset with the augmented data as part of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common approach used in Tensorflow is to create an augmented training set on the fly, applying random distortions to the input images.

The Tensorflow authors use the on the fly method even in the official tutorial on the CNNs: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn#convolutional-neural-networks

In particular the on-the-fly augmentation starts here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py#L171